# Are there any general purpose CRUD client applications?

Tags: php, curl, crud

I'm creating a CRUD style API using PHP Tonic that uses the same URL (for instance /somepath/person) to which you can do POST, GET, PUT and DELETE requests. But I've run into a problem with testing the API. It's obviously easy to test GET (just visit the URL with a browser) but how can I test the remaining 3 request methods?

I'm imagining a desktop CRUD client where I get a simple text box in which to put query parameters, an URL box and a send button.

Does an application like this already exist, or will I have to make one?

---

*Alternative question, can I use CURL for this? In which case, how?*

Comment: Assuming your server side implementation is RESTful then testing with curl should be trivial.

Comment: I'm looking into it. I can definitively see the use for a graphical client though. The commands are already getting really long

Comment: I suppose you could write a client application that utilises curl to curry the requests out for you which should make writing them easier.  However I'm not aware of any existing software that does that.  At least not software that issues general purpose requests.  There are several apps that use a RESTful API for communicating with a server of course, but they're obviously tied to particular tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , Very good question! The following Chrome extensions can get the job done

- [Advanced REST client Application](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)
- [REST Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn)
- [Postman REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm)

---

Second answer, yes curl can do the job for you - [here's an example](http://singletonio.blogspot.com/2009/07/simple-php-rest-client-using-curl.html).

Comment: I like the links, but I'm hesitant to mark this answer as correct since you say that "you need an app that runs on the browser" which is clearly untrue. I'll edit the answer a bit and mark it correct, feel free to rollback if you don't agree with my changes

Answer (score 2):

I've used the plugin "Advanced REST Client Application" for Chrome and it work perfectly and is easy to use.